# autofocus attribute not working on display state change

Tags: jquery, html, autofocus

I want to add autofocus to a form. That is working fine, but for the search form I also use a display status change, from none to block and back again.

The first time the autofocus works fine, but after hiding the form and displaying it again, the autofocus does not work anymore.

Is there a way to achieve this by jQuery? And what code do I need?

HTML:

```
<div class="header-search">
                            <div class="search-container">
                                <div class="overwrite-setting">
                                    <i class="sf-icon-search"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="switcher-content">
                                    <form id="search_mini_form" action="https://www.redable.nl/catalogsearch/result/" method="get">
    <div class="form-search">
        <input id="search" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Zoeken naar..." type="text" name="q" value="" class="input-text" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off">
        <button type="submit" title="Zoek" class="search-button"><span><span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span></span></button>
        <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
</form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.header-setting .overwrite-setting').click(function() {
    jQuery('.setting-switcher .switcher-content').toggle();
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
    return false;
})
if(jQuery(window).width() > 1024){
 jQuery('.header-maincart .icon-cart-header').click(function() {
    jQuery('.header-maincart .cart-wrapper').toggle();
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
    return false;
})
}
jQuery('.header-search .overwrite-setting').click(function() {
    jQuery('.search-container .switcher-content').toggle();
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
    return false;
})

jQuery(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    if(jQuery(window).width() > 1024){
        if(jQuery('.header-maincart').has(e.target).length == 0 && jQuery('.cart-wrapper').has(e.target).length == 0 ){
            jQuery('.header-maincart .cart-wrapper').hide();
            jQuery('.header-maincart .icon-cart-header').removeClass('active');
        }
    }
    if(jQuery('.header-search .overwrite-setting').has(e.target).length == 0 && jQuery('.search-container .switcher-content').has(e.target).length == 0){
        jQuery('.search-container .switcher-content').hide();
        jQuery('.header-search .overwrite-setting').removeClass('active');
    }
    if(jQuery('.header-setting .overwrite-setting').has(e.target).length == 0 && jQuery('.setting-switcher .switcher-content').has(e.target).length == 0){
        jQuery('.setting-switcher .switcher-content').hide();
        jQuery('.header-setting .overwrite-setting').removeClass('active');
    }


});
```

Comment: How exactly do you hide/display the input?

Comment: You should trigger .focus() after hide and display, I think.

Comment: @Dekel Thanks! I updated my question.

Comment: Great, did you check my answer ? :)

Comment: @Dekel Yes, thanks! I checked it. But in my case it is when clicking on the .search-container .overwrite-setting. How can I achieve that?

Comment: whenever you show the element (or the container), just add `$('#search').focus()`, as you can see in my example.

Comment: @Dekel Thanks! I tried this, but that does not seem to work. What am I missing? `jQuery('.header-search .overwrite-setting').click(function() {
    jQuery('.search-container .switcher-content').toggle();
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
    return false;
    jQuery('#search').focus();
})`

Comment: you should put it **before** the `return false;` :)

Comment: @Dekel, Thanks, that was quite stopid, works perfect! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you hide/show the `input`, but you can use the `focus` function on the element after you show it:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#search').toggle().focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Zoeken naar..." type="text" name="q" value="" class="input-text" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off">
<button>Click to hide/show the button</button>
```